# When using Eclipse and Egit I can not push to upstream

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Every time I try to push I get reject non-fast forward. If I push from the terminal it works just fine.

I am using Ubuntu Natty
latest eclipse
Egit plugin
git https

I would rather use ssh, but I can not get that to work either.

Comment: Fairly odd... I might try the egit mailing list on this, then, since if it works with git but not egit it is likely a bug. I never understood the point of egit - why does eclipse not use git itself?

Comment: You did follow all instructions on http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide, especially how to identify yourself (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Identifying_yourself)?

Answer (score 2):

Windows->Preferences->Team->Git->Configuration->Repository Settings->Add Entry

Just add two key: 'merge' and 'remote' like the following pic.

1. key(branch.master.merge)  -- value(refs/heads/master)
2. key(branch.master.remote) -- value(origin)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this one can help... because I ever having problem when pushing in eclipse but not in cmd. So I try to modify the Eclipse network connection setting

- Go to Window -> Preference
- General -> Network Connection --> SSH2
- The problem could be inside there.

Or if it doesn't work,..

have you try again to re-setup, and Follow the guide http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide exactly

Hope it helps, Good luck, :)